# Hide Layout to unauthenticated users in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, layout, next.js

I am currently using one Layout for all pages inside my application, like the basic example in the Next JS Docs as a wrapper inside the _app.js file. If a user is not signed in and therefore unauthenticated, only the sign-in page should be accessible and the Layout and therefore the Header etc. should also be inaccessible/invisible for the user.

If I wrap my whole app inside a condition that checks for the auth-state it also hides the sign-in page, but if I only apply it to the Layout my App itself doesn't get rendered inside my Layout anymore, but beneath because I cannot nest both Layout and App inside the condition.

How do I manage to not show my Layout when a user is unauthenticated or just not apply it to the sign-in page?

Comment: create a separate layout component and use it where it's necessary, as shown in this [project](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devspace-blog)

Comment: It looks like you hit the limitations of standard layouts quickly - you need to use multiple layouts - check out option 4 - https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/  I also wrap my whole app in a context that listens for route changes via effect hook that only allows auth (sign-in/up, forgot PW, 2FA, recover PW) routes. The others are redirected to sign in. If a user is set, then the auth routes are redirected home.

Comment: I see, thank you! I thought about using getLayout as well, I just did not expect to hit the limitations of standard layouts that quickly, as Sean said. I thought it would be such a common use case that I was overlooking some neat trick. I already read that article, and I wondered since it was writte in October 2019, are there any things that I have to look out for or implement differently. I assume there has been some development regarding Next and React, or is that article still up to date?

Comment: Regarding the listener for route changes that wraps about my application. That sounds good, could you drop some more keywords so I know a little bit better what to gooole to learn more about that as well? I am really new to react and programming in general. But your advice is really helpful!! Thank you!

Comment: In his article, the _app.js file contains a class component instead of a functional component for example. Or is that just me being overly cautious?

Comment: I also found this article which is a little bit more up to date but uses the same approach https://www.cutintothejamstack.com/articles/dynamic-content-nextjs-shared-layouts#nested-layouts

Comment: FYI, the official Next.js docs also cover the layout pattern: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts.